# Jtidy filter seems not to be called

Tags: java, servlets, jboss7.x, servlet-filters, jtidy

I'm trying to test the Jtidy filter on a ridiculously simple hello world Struts project.

I'm following [other answers that were given here in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671138/how-can-you-strip-html-comments-out-of-a-page-generated-with-jsp-jstl).

I do not get any errors during deployment or accessing JSPs. But it seems like the filter does nothing. i.e. no html comments are being removed from the created html's.

The Struts filter seems to work fine.. since my Action class is getting called.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>JTidyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.w3c.tidy.servlet.filter.JTidyFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>indent: auto; indent-spaces: 2; hide-comments: true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JTidyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

What might I be doing wrong here?
How can I find out, if I don't get any exceptions?

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.tidy.servlet.filter.JTidyFilter`, so it's not working for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I had to change the filter order of execution, so that the Jtidy filter will be called last (after the Struts filter has completed its work):

**The new web.xml:**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Struts 2 Web Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>JTidyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.w3c.tidy.servlet.filter.JTidyFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>indent: auto; indent-spaces: 2; hide-comments: true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JTidyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Second, I had to have on the classpath not only the `jtidyservlet` jar, but also the `jtidy` jar (without the latter, compilation went fine but I would get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.tidy.TidyMessageListener` in runtime).

**in my pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jtidy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtidyservlet</artifactId>
    <version>r8-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
    <version>r8-21122004</version>
</dependency>
```

I also had to add the `jtidyservlet` jar manually to my local maven repo:

1. Download `jtidyservlet-r8-SNAPSHOT.jar` from: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/nightly/
2. Drop it in `C:\TEMP`
3. Run from command line:

`SET LOCAL_JARS=C:\TEMP`

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jtidy -DartifactId=jtidyservlet -Dversion=r8-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=%LOCAL_JARS%\jtidyservlet-r8-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgeneratePom=true`